# ASP.NET URL rewriting and tag the old URL to 301

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

Hi I'm trying to rewrite my url: www.mydomain.com/hw/Index.aspx to www.mydomain.com/hello-world/index.aspx . here is my code in web.config:

```
    <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^hello-world/index.aspx" />
      <action type="rewrite" url="hw/Index.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

the problem with this is I am having two Url with just the same page.

1. www.mydomain.com/hw/Index.aspx
2. www.mydomain.com/hello-world/index.aspx

What I wanna do is when the user browse the **www.mydomain.com/hw/Index.aspx**
it will be tagged as 301 and will redirect to **www.mydomain.com/hello-world/index.aspx**

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A `rewrite` essentially makes IIS serve the same page to the user, it internally re-writes the URL and passes that to your application.

On the other hand, a `rewrite` actually sends a response to the client that the resource being requested has moved (i.e a 301)

To fix this, change the action type from `rewrite` to `redirect`:

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^hello-world/index.aspx" />
  <action type="redirect" url="hw/Index.aspx" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi DavidG, the problem with this is it will always redirect my Url to **www.mydomain.com/hw/Index.aspx** not to **www.mydomain.com/hello-world/index.aspx**. What I need is **www.mydomain.com/hello-world/index.aspx**. please advise.

Comment: Your rule is just back to front,  switch the values for the match and the action url.